# Distinct Types from a generic Collection

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of objects

```
List<Animals> animals
```

I'm trying to access every distinct `Type` of animal inside `animals` (e.g. `Dog`, `Cat`, `Walrus`) and get it into another generic collection using this kind of idea:

```
List<Type> types 
    = animals.SelectMany<Animal, Type>(a => a.GetType()).Distinct<Type>();
```

or

```
// EqualityComparer<T> is a generic implementation of IEqualityComparer<T>
List<Type> types 
    = animals.Distinct<Animal>(new EqualityComparer<Animal>((a, b) => a.GetType() == b.GetType()));
```

But I'm having trouble getting either of these to compile.

Comment: Could you please you try to explain "this kind of idea"? I'm afraid that this pseudo code is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `Dictionary<Type, List<Animal>>` where any list within the list only contains elements of the key type?

```
var typeSpecficGroups = animals.GroupBy(animal => animal.GetType());
var dictOfTypes = typeSpecficGroups.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Now you can ask the dictionary if it has a specific animal and get the corresponding list of animals back. The drawback is that you have to cast each element within the list to the concrete type:

```
List<Animal> matchingList;

if (dictOfTypes.TryGetValue(typeof(Dog), out matchingList))
{
    var dogs = matchingList.Cast<Dog>();

    foreach (var dog in dogs)
    {
        dog.FindBone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why `SelectMany`? Standard `Select` should do the job:

```
List<Type> types = animals.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct();
```

Comment: It needed: `.ToList<Type>()` but this works perfectly, thanks.